# com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.NoHostAvailableException:

Tags: cassandra, kundera

I'm using Cassandra with Kundera that is installed on UBUNTU environment and I'm getting this Error:
**com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.NoHostAvailableException:**

I'm using the DSClient Protocol (com.impetus.kundera.client.cassandra.dsdriver.DSClientFactory) and also port 9042. 
What's interenting is when I test it Local (on my widons environment) it works, but trying to access Linux, (where cassandra is installed) it does't works.

Do you know something about it?

`persistence.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">

    <persistence-unit name="default-cassandra-kundera-persistence-unit"
        transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <class>com.blablabla.model</class>
        <exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

I'm setting the configurations manually, like this:

```
public static final String PROPERTY_KUNDERA_CLIENT = "kundera.client.lookup.class";
public static final String CASSANDRA_DATASTAX_CLIENT = "com.impetus.kundera.client.cassandra.dsdriver.DSClientFacto‌​ry"; 
persistenceUnitProperties.put(PROPERTY_KUNDERA_CLIENT, CASSANDRA_DATASTAX_CLIENT );
```

Comment: share your `persistence.xml`, Entity and Kundera and Cassandra version

Comment: Read the question again. It's not clear about  working on windows or Linux?

Comment: Kundera: 3.4
Cassandra: 3.0.0

Comment: Please share your `persistence.xml` and entity. You can chat with us (_Kundera team_)  at [Gitter](https://gitter.im/impetus-opensource/Kundera) for any question or discussion regarding Kundera.

Comment: Have you checked [Kundera in 5 minutes](https://github.com/impetus-opensource/Kundera/wiki/Getting-Started-in-5-minutes)?

Comment: Yeh I've checked it  'Kundera in 5 minutes'. ;(

Comment: I'm trying a lot of approaches, but I'm facing a lot of problems. I was using the Trihft Protocol, but a got a error reguarding the frame size, now I'm tryng to paginate the data using com.impetus.kundera.query.Query setFechSize, but the query just retrive one result from Cassandra.